# MySQL Server Remote Connect

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2012-r2

I've set up a `MySQL` server through `GCS VMs`, Set up all of the required users, etc however I can't remotely connect.

I've opened the ports through firewall, given all the required permissions, made sure the server is running and just about every other method I've found so far. I checked the `my.ini` file (Using 8.0 on Windows 2012 R2) and found no 'bind-address' value or similar in the file.

I've assigned a static IP, ran:

```
"CREATE USER 'root'@'%' identified by 'password'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'root'@'$';"
```

and I'm getting the error

```
Cannot connect to database server...
unable to connect to...
```

any help to do with remote connection appreciated :)

Comment: MySQL has its own access permission - you need to grant access within the server too eg `MariaDB [(none)]> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)`

Comment: The bind-address should be `bind-address=0.0.0.0` and execute the following command `GRANT ALL ON <database_name>.* TO <username>@'*' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';` on mysql shell

Comment: What is the error? What is the connect method or command? Edit your question with details.

Comment: is the GCP firewall well configured?

this is because gcp has a dedicated firewall to protect the VMs